# Sticky header not working correctly on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, header, sticky

I'm trying to achieve a sticky header where nothing happens until you scroll beyond 100-150px. than on scroll up it is revealed and on scroll down it is hidden again also returning to it's state of origin when you scroll back to the top of the page.

This is the exact look/feel I'm going for

https://medium.com/@heykylehey/making-the-practice-print-6c8292934932

Here's a link to my dev site

http://www.alexcoven.com/dev/element/

with this script

```
  var $body = $("body");
  var $wrapperTop = $(".sticky-container");
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if(st < 100){
         $body.removeClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
         $wrapperTop.removeClass("animated fadeOutUp");
     }
     if(st < lastScrollTop) {
         $body.addClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
         $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass("animated fadeInDown");
     } else if((st > lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
         $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

This needs to launch today and I'm stressin' over this issue please help
Much love!

Comment: They are working exactly the same for me. Windows 10 Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: It's glitchy if you scroll up to the top you'll see that it still has the classes header--fixed-up header--fixed on the body.

Comment: I think it's because on scroll up it adds the class's even before 100px I just don't know how to fix that or add a conditional that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed!

```
var $body = $("body");
      var $wrapperTop = $(".sticky-container");
      var lastScrollTop = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function(event){
         var st = $(this).scrollTop();
         if(st < 3){
             $body.removeClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
             $wrapperTop.removeClass("animated fadeInDown fadeOutUp");
         }
         if((st < lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
             $body.addClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
             $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass("animated fadeInDown");
         } else if((st > lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
             $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
         }
         lastScrollTop = st;
      });
```

I changed the value of my first if statement to st < 3 so that it returns to it's origin when your back at the top of the page with no hiccup do to padding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(st < 100){
     $body.removeClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
     $wrapperTop.removeClass("animated fadeOutUp");
 }else if(st < lastScrollTop) {
     $body.addClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
     $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass("animated fadeInDown");
 } else if((st > lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
     $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
 }
 lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: any explanation along would make this a valuable answer, not just a bone to chew ;)

Comment: It's because the code is entering in the two if's so it makes it glitchy

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not working 100%

```
  var $body = $("body");
  var $wrapperTop = $(".sticky-container");
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if(st < 100){
         $body.removeClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
         $wrapperTop.removeClass("animated fadeOutUp");
     }
     if((st < lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
         $body.addClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
         $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass("animated fadeInDown");
     } else if((st > lastScrollTop) && (st > 100)) {
         $wrapperTop.removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
         //$body.removeClass("header--fixed-up header--fixed");
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

I got it closer but still having an issue with when I return to top of the page.

By adding

```
&& (st > 100))
```

To this line

```
if((st < lastScrollTop) && (st > 100))
```

This is now changing that line to say if you scroll up and your beyond 100px on the page execute instead of if you scroll up execute ;)